# Render subsection, produce full resolution image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation, camera

## Background

In an animation, text scrolls horizontally across the screen (from left to right), stopping on the far right. For example:

[image: Animation]

The background is transparent and no other objects are in the scene. Blender creates PNG frames at 720p, as expected.

## Problem

Blender spends time rendering image parts that will only be transparent. The <kbd>CTRL+b</kbd> command allows for rendering a subsection of the image, but appears to produce an image that is not 720p.

## Question

How would you create a 1280x720 PNG image but only render a horizontal band (see below) where the text is animated?

[image: Example Render]

## Related

- [Render just part of a final image from Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301/render-just-part-of-a-final-image-from-cycles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, using the render border (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) will still produce a full image according to the set render resolution (I think this what you want).

The image will only be cropped to the border region if *Crop* is enabled in *Render settings > Dimensions*:

[image]

With *Crop* **disabled**, only the border region will be rendered, and the rest of the image will be filled with transparency.