# Is it possible to only render a part of my scene?

Tags: rendering

I made an animation where marbles fall down and roll away over a logo. Logo is passive there's a floor. Not very hard if you know a little about blender.
But...
Since i want to render 250 frames it takes a very long time. In the last 100 frames only the left quarter of my scene changes since there are still marbles rolling out of my scene.
I think its useless to render parts again that are exactly the same as the former frame.
So my question...
Is it possible to only render a part of my scene?
If not i think that defenitely should be made possible in upcoming versions ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301/render-just-part-of-a-final-image-from-cycles

Answer (score 1):

You could border-render a certain part of your timeline, so that you only render the interesting/changing bits. In a second step you can composite the last fully rendered frame with the partial renders.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that possibillity a little googeling (probably) solved my problem.

Comment: If it solves your problem, please mark my answer as "accepted answer".

Comment: Could you not use render layers?? Have the background as one layer and the animated parts as another... I'm not an animator yet so not sure if it'd work... Just an idea...