# How to set the viewport to render size?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

My final render is 10k pixel wide.

In order to view this current size I

1. Make a fast low quality render
2. Save the render as png
3. Open the png in firefox
4. Zoom in to current size

Can this be done in the blender viewport?

Tried the values under Render properties > Quality to no avail

Comment: Do you have a 10k display? Suggest use the render region feature to iterate quickly: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301/render-just-part-of-a-final-image-from-cycles

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but in Camera View you can use View->Navigation->Zoom Camera 1:1.

Comment: @Sanoronas Indeed even the tooltip says exactly what I'm looking for. Yet, it's smaller than in the browser (100% zoom).