# Camera to user view?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, camera

Let's suppose we have a medium-poly mesh, and we want to snapshot several different closeups by just flying in the camera or using the user's perspective to flyover.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for adding a camera to the user's current view without all having to moving the camera all over the scene to fit a desired position? The switching back and forth from user perspectives to camera view is annoying.

Comment: You can see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43/whats-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-point-the-camera-somewhere-in-blender

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To make your active camera match up with the viewport, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, the other zero won't work).
Also, you can track the camera to an empty with the *Track To* constraint. This will force your camera to point to the empty, which you can place in the center of your *medium complexity face mesh*.

**To set up the *Track To* constraint:**

1. Select your empty first, then camera.

[image: Both selected, camera is brighter because it is the active object]

2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> key, and choose *Track To* from the menu.

[image: Contraint Menu Pops Up]

3. Then, go to the *Properties panel > Object Constraints tab*. The *Target:* should say **Empty**. Change the *To:* axis to *-Z* and the *Up:* axis to *Y*.

[image: Track To Constraint]

Now your camera will always point to the empty, making things easier for you to position.

Comment: Thanks, I got my rep score up, so I was able to add the screen shots.

Comment: yep but my original question was retrieved and altered and now it doesn't fit the original purpose. what you think?

Comment: can this be done with menus? Ubuntu will close the window if i press those keys

Comment: @cammil System Settings -> Keyboard -> Minimize Key -> Set it to 'CTRL ALT 0'. Not the Numpad-0 of course. I'm pretty happy I found this shortcut in Ubuntu! +2 if I could. I used a similar shortcut in MacOSX for the longest time and never new it existed in Ubuntu.

Comment: Or accessible through the (space key) menu : "align camera to view".

Comment: For @cammil and also my future self: it's found in the menus at View > Align View > Align Active Camera To View.

Answer (score 20):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> will snap the active camera to your viewport position :)

Comment: How do you do this with menus or the Python api? I am on ubuntu and ctrl+alt+0 will close the active window.

Comment: It works under windows

Comment: Its because in windows CTRL+ALT+Numpad 0 is not associated to any system functionality, in UBUNTU it is used to minimize window. There is simple solution, just change shortcut in blender to CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+Numpad 0. Here https://askubuntu.com/a/618581/69037 is described ho to do that.