# how to render in user perspective and not camera perspective

Tags: rendering

When I render an image, the render uses the camera perspective. What setting do I need to change to have the render show the user perspective?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43/whats-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-point-the-camera-somewhere-in-blender and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/877/camera-to-user-view

Comment: If you don't specifically need a final render (F12), perhaps you might use [rendered viewport shading](http://blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/shading.html)? (Shift Z)

Comment: One year latter, Blender still does not allow you to render the view point you have when modeling, sculpting, or so working your models. It lacks this free render choice, as you spend more and more time to put many cameras, and don't forget to adjust the clip parameters. The clip parameters stands for the rendered distances, from where (said from the lens of the camera), to where (the end, the max rendered distance from the camera lens). If your objects are too far away from the camera, they wan't render, so you have to put a big end clip parameter. But this said, Blender still (despite it's f

Answer (score 4):

There is no real way to do that. (For example many settings like defocus depend on the camera object.) You simply will have to move the camera around.

Firstly: You can move the camera around like any object (grab with G, rotate with R and scale with S), but it is easier to go to the camera perspective (numpad 0) and enter fly mode (Shift+F). This allows you to position the camera in a more practical way. (See this in more detail here: https://youtu.be/xcZmyD9jkI4)

Secondly: If you want to save the camera's position for some reason, you can simply add a new one to the scene (Shift+A) and set it to be the active camera by pressing the Ctrl + 0 hotkey. Now the scene will be rendered from it and hitting 0 will make you look through it. You can tell which camera is active by looking at the camera object from another view: the small triangle above it is filled when it's active.

Thirdly: If your user perspective is "just the right way", you can align the camera to it (I can't remember the hotkey, but hitting space and looking for something along the lines of "Align camera to view" should get it).

Comment: There is also an addon that allows locking the active camera to the view, so if you orbit, pan or dolly the view, the camera follows. It is available on [Github](https://github.com/lapineige/Blender_add-ons/blob/master/LockCamToView_HeaderView3D.py). Enable the addon, create a camera, view the scene through the camera (numpad 0 key), then press the button in the 3d view header to lock the camera to the view.

Answer (score 2):

this can be achieved only for 3D view port. Here you have to go:

[image: Blender button for render the 3D viewport]

So the result will be the object+outline[unselected, selected, active] color without grid and axis lines.

[image]

keep in mind that the size of the render will be rounded on width and height present in the properties window under render tab, or with shift+z you can render the final scene with the user perspective, but with a complex scene this can be a pain for your cpu

Answer (score 2):

You cannot actually render from the user perspective (excluding OpenGL viewport quality renders). Instead, you can simple move the camera to the user perspective using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. If you want the camera to stay locked to the view, there is an option to do that in the properties panel (accessed by hitting <kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You **can** easily switch between Perspective and Orthographic rendering, not just the viewport as other answers may suggest.

1. Select the camera you wish to change. Right Click the camera so that it is selected and appears orange.
2. Select the camera's *Data* tab (circled in red below)
   [image: Screen shot of the Data Tab Button]
3. Select *Orthographic*
   [image]
4. Adjust the *Orthographic Scale* to ensure objects are within the camera's view.

Comment: I don't think this question was asking how to change between Orthographic and Perspective.