# Alternative ways of controlling camera, other functions

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I am new to Blender, and at this point I'm trying to learn how to position the camera in order to see what I'm doing.  The problem is I cannot use the mouse or keyboard.  I have an eye tracking device for mouse control, which also includes an on-screen keyboard.  However, the shortcut hotkeys do not respond to my on-screen keyboard, which is the case for other programs I have used.  In addition, I cannot do a combination of holding a certain key while doing a certain mouse click, or holding down the middle mouse button while dragging.  So I have no way of positioning the camera in some very basic ways.  Are there there are alternative ways of moving the camera, such as using macros like autohotkey?

Comment: See the answer in this post about tracking an empty.  I find it very handy.  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/877/camera-to-user-view/879#879

Answer (score 1):

Go into Camera View <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

Enable Lock Camera to View.

Press <kbd>N</kbd> or open the Controls Region (or click on the triangle at the top right of the 3D vieport), in the view tab enable Lock Camera to View.

[image]

Then you can naviage like you do with other views or using the numeric pad.

<kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> will rotate left right.

<kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 2</kbd> will rotate up and down

<kbd>Numpad +</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> willmove the camera forward and back

For Version 7.9:

[image]