# How to increase this camera viewport size?

Tags: rendering, camera

[image]
[image]
How can I increase the size of the viewport(I don't know the exact name of it)
The frame in the middle.
I tried several methods, but I failed.
Only I can do is just zoom in and out, but that's not what I wanted.
The SECOND picture is the way that I wanted to.
Make the frame large without zoom-in or out.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate or deactivate the *N* panel > *View > Camera to View* option if you want your camera to follow or not your zoom in and out:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I will try!

Comment: @user112966 Hello and welcome. Please don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you question correctly, I believe changing the values in the focal length on the camera could solve your question.

Select the camera in the viewport, go to "Object Data Properties" (little green camera seen in image), and adjust the focal length. You can also adjust the size just below if you toggle down the "Camera" setting.

35mm is one of the standard sizes used in filming, same as 12mm but I always found that to distorted.

[image: Details Panel]

[image: 50mm focal length]

[image: 35mm Focal length]

Comment: Thanks ! I will try !

Comment: @user112966 Hello and welcome. Please don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through camera options and found nothing to change the size of this rectangle **keeping other settings the same**. I'm afraid you must do a zoom in with a mouse wheel, followed by the decrease in focal length to get the result shown in your second image.

Comment: You can change the size of the output under "Output settings" and then changing the resolution of X and Y, therefore changing the size of the box.

Comment: been looking for the answer for this. Only this solves my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hit the <kbd>Home</kbd> key on the keyboard, took me ages to find this from someone else's post.

Post here: [Can I change the size of the camera view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42275/can-i-change-the-size-of-the-camera-view)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know this also.
My Apple MacBook.
Select Camera view, and camera object.

Make sure the View Lock "Camera to View" button is OFF! When set to ON it the following only alters the zoom (this is what got me).

Hover over the "frame".
On the trackpad, it is 'control' or 'command' and a 'two finger' vertical swipe alters the size.