# Can I render without the camera?

Tags: rendering, camera

Ok I really do not like the camera part of rendering. I can easily line up a good looking model without the camera but I keep realizing you need the camera to render into an image file. Is there anyway I can render without the camera and then download into a image?

Comment: short answer is: no. You can render from the viewport, but that is a bit different and much more limited.

Comment: Set the camera to view Ctrl Alt Numpad0  Read also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43/whats-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-point-the-camera-somewhere-in-blender/487#487

Comment: ....And there's the N toolbar > View > Lock Camera to View. Mine's on a shortcut. Then you can move the camera with your normal viewport controls.

Answer (score 3):

In some way, you can do this with:
`3D Viewport ‣ View ‣ Viewport Render`
but you have to keep in mind it won't be standard render. You will have to disable from rendering viewport overlays, like: floor, axis etc.

Examples:

Standard render:
[image]

Standard viewport render:
[image]

Viewport render without viewport overlays:
[image]

More info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/viewport_render.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you need a camera to render, however you could use viewport rendering as user1660210 mentioned, this however does not allow for you to save an image.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: You can save a viewport render.  On the render popup window, look on the menu options.