# How to set the camera position and rotation to my view position and rotation?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Hello I have many problems with poitioning the camera in blender. ( I am a noob sorry)

But what is the way / shortcut to position the camera  to my view so it will see what I see in the editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the quickest, easiest way to point the camera somewhere in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43/whats-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-point-the-camera-somewhere-in-blender)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the camera and use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num 0</kbd> shortcut. You may also do it via *View*-->*Align View*-->*Active Camera to View*.

[image]