# Why can't I get the camera view like in the tutorial?

Tags: modeling

In this tutorial: Create a Realistic City - Blender Tutorial

At 10:36 he presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>

When I do the same I get nothing but an empty view.
Then he goes back to object mode and can play with the camera zoom in out.

I'm now in edit mode and everything selected.

[image: everything selected edit mode]

And more or less I'm in same position as he is.

Now when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> I get this:

[image: Ctrl alt numpad0]

Not even close to what he did.

Comment: This is the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4ySFm4ey9U&t=328s at minute 10:55 you can see the view he is in and it's nothing like what i'm getting.

Comment: To learn how to move the camera, read: [What's the quickest, easiest way to point the camera somewhere in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43/whats-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-point-the-camera-somewhere-in-blender)

Comment: Most likely the clipping distance for the camera (not  for the viewport) is set incorrectly.

Comment: @testman tm the clipping value you have is the same he uses in the video, but the clipping values are always relative to the scale of your scene/objects, so you maybe you have different scaling, and so you need to adjust them to fit your specific scene.

Answer (score 3):

The clipping distance for the camera is probably too short. With the Camera selected, go to the Camera tab and adjust the End parameter to something more appropriate for the scale of the scene.

[image]

After you've done that, you can play with the position, focal length, and sensor size to get the look you're going for.