# Why is everything white when rendering?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I don't know what I've done wrong, but it's the first time that this is happening to me. I made an animation with different color falling solids and when I render it, everything is white. Here is my file so you can look it up maybe.
PS: I know it may have something t do with texture/material but I am too much of a noob to solve my problem.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NKckJdAOTi7XXVRXuomuJoq2ppG-QDpV

Comment: your camera seems to point to the void/empty space. Also, please use https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgAFv.gif to post screenshots as it will directly embed them, allow you to organize them in your question as well as ensure long term archival instead of an external link that may vanish in the future. Also, if need be, attach your blender file using this: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ instead of gdrive or dropbox.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank

Answer (score 1):

What gets rendered is the camera view.

Your camera is aimed to a place where there are no objects.

[image]

Please read:[What's the quickest, easiest way to point the camera somewhere in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43/whats-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-point-the-camera-somewhere-in-blender/53#53)

Comment: I pressed numpad 0 to be sure that my camera points where objects fall. I see them fall plus I even changed the sky color (which sould be seen from any view of course?) and everything is still white.

Comment: https://imgur.com/YBwSiRK