# Camera option won't work?

Tags: rendering, camera

I'm trying to render a Roblox character but the camera won't work. I've tried pressing just 0 which made my whole character disappear, I also tried doing ctrl+0 but it said "Modifiers cannot be added to object camera 001". It seems like I'm the only one with this problem.. Can anyone help? :(

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct camera and that such camera is aiming at the object you want to see. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43/whats-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-point-the-camera-somewhere-in-blender

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a classic missing-numblock problem because your on a laptop or mac?
if so: User Preferences->Input->Emulate Numpad

Comment: no I know its not the keyboard because it does recognise that Im wanting to use the camera option but it just simply won't let me.

Comment: do you have a file? Maby something is strange there..

Comment: @nachocheese No it doesn't your saying it states **Modifiers cannot be added to object camera 001** when pressing *Ctrl 0*. However, this only happens when you press `0` on the number row instead of the numpad.