# Setting the Camera view

Tags: camera

So.. i am designing a GUI.. and I want the camera to point straight at the Rectangle\cube that I am working on so that when  I render the Cube is perfectly straight on sides\top\bottom..

In C4D I would add a camera then go to its coordinates and just zero out all rotation and voila.. when i render Its 'straight on'

How do i achieve this in Blender?

I am an absolute beginner.

TIA !

Comment: Read the following link: [What is the quickest easiest way to point the camera somewhere in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43/whats-the-quickest-easiest-way-to-point-the-camera-somewhere-in-blender/82067#82067)

Answer (score 2):

Use the numpad keys to get the (orthographic) view you want

<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> = front,

<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> = side,

<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> = top,

<kbd>Numpad 9</kbd> = flip (ex: top becomes bottom).

To toggle orthographic and perspective view use  <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>

When you have the correct side, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to snap the camera to your viewport view.

To get more specific, select the camera and press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the tool menu where you can adjust values manually (such as distance).

Comment: @Cristopher Bennett, you can use markup to indicate keyboard shortcuts like this: <kbd> Letter </kbd>

Comment: Wow.. that was easy.. lol.. Thanks y'all I 'preciate ya!

Answer (score 0):

To clear the rotation on the camera: Select the camera press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and the camera will be zeroed on the rotation (<kbd>R</kbd> is the shortcut for rotation)

The default rotation is with the camera looking down at the ground on the Negative $Z$ axis.

Likewise, to move the camera to the origin coordinates use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>